# Wordpress : hooking data inserted event in custom table

Tags: wordpress, hook

In my Wordpress system, there is a custom table call : wp_testing_data_table for example

In a function we used :

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "jet_testing_data_table";
$data = [
..............
]
$wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        $data,
    );
```

So, I need to do this thing :
After data was saved into database, I need to send these data into a REST API

I already created a new plugin, in this plugin can I hook into insert event of above code to send data to REST API.
I don't want to modify old plugin directly, that's why I need to create new plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: The only halfway relevant hook I can spot is `query` in https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php#L2226, and that even executes before the actual query gets performed. _Why_ do you need to handle functionality that clearly appears to be related, in two separate plugins? Doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Just add a `do_action` in the old plugin, and `add_action` in the new one. That would be the best way. Using `query` is too early as errors might happen, using `log_query_custom_data` would be an option as that's triggered after a query's run, but so much overhead that can be avoided by adding one line of code to the old plugin.